# “pointer-events: none” does not work in IE9 and IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Good morning,
I want to make one link as non clickable 
This is my `css`.

```
         .disable {
            pointer-events: none;
            cursor: not-allowed !important;
            opacity: 0.5;
          }
```

This code will work well in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome but not in IE 9 or IE 10.
So I want to ask if there is any option for `pointer-events: none;`  this property.

Comment: do you want to disabled `input` and `button`. If yes then you can use `disabled="disabled"` attribute.

Answer (score 4):

**Pointer-events**  is not supported for IE9/10. It will only supported IE11.
See this link: http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: that is not an answer. OP knows about it.

Comment: So if you want to disable any link then you have to try it with jQuery, let me provide you a demo to disable click on anchor link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="disable">test</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".disable").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    })

});
```

CSS:

```
.disable,.disable:active {
      cursor:default;
      opacity: 0.5;
      color:blue; 

}
```